# Present or future in this context?

Tags: present-tense

Would it be possible to email me on a basis of every 2 months the latest records you have for sale .

I was wondering if I wrote "will have" instead of "have"  what would be the change of the meaning .
I think present is better because this list of new records will be sent every 2 months and will become regular as a general fact .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quibble: I wouldn't say "on the basis of". This is awkward and doesn't add anything. I'd just say, "Would it be possible to email me every 2 months ..." But that said ...

I'd use the present tense, "have". You want the list of the records that they have at the time they send the email. You don't want them to email you every 2 months with a list of records they will have at some time in the future of that email. (At least I presume that's what you mean.) If you said "the records you will have", I think a reader would wonder, "Will have when? A month after they send the email? Two months? Etc."

It would be pointless for them to email you a list every 2 months of the records they have now, i.e. the same list every two months. So I think most readers would immediately dismiss that possibility, if it even occurred to them.

I suppose in other contexts it might not be clear. In that case, you could add words to clarify. Like, "Email me every 2 months with a list of records that you have at that time".